# How do I change HTML elements with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an external JS file, with the function time().
In my HTML, I have

```
<p id="sentence"> </p>
<script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript">
    time();
</script>
```

The time function calculates how much time there is left until a certain hour, I checked with `console.log()` and the algorithm is good.
I wanna display the output to `<p>`
I tried:

```
document.getElementByID("sentence").innerHTML= ("Happy hour starts in " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
```

What am I missing?

Edit: the time function as requested:

```
function time() {
    let date = new Date();
    date.setHours(16);
    date.setMinutes(0);
    let day = date.getDate();
    date.setSeconds(0)
    date.setMilliseconds(0); // set happy hour for the day
    let interval = date - Date.now(); //calculate ms between current time and happy hour time
    //case when happy hour is later than current date, on the same day

    if (interval > 0) {
        const hour = Math.floor(interval / 3600000);
        interval -= 3600000 * Math.floor(interval / 3600000);
        const minutes = Math.floor(interval / 60000)
        interval -= 60000 * Math.floor(interval / 60000);
        const seconds = Math.floor(interval / 1000);
        document.getElementByid("sentence").innerHTML= ("Happy hour starts in " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
    } else if (interval < 0 && interval < -3600000) { //happy hour gone, time left until it starts tomorrow
        date.setDate(++day);
        console.log(date);
        interval = date - Date.now();
        const hour = Math.floor(interval / 3600000);
        interval -= 3600000 * Math.floor(interval / 3600000);
        const minutes = Math.floor(interval / 60000);
        interval -= 60000 * Math.floor(interval / 60000);
        const seconds = Math.floor(interval / 1000)
        document.getElementByid("sentence").innerHTML= ("Happy hour starts in " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
    } else { //happy hour started, but didn't finish yet
        const hour = Math.floor(interval / 3600000);
        interval -= 3600000 * Math.floor(interval / 3600000);
        const minutes = Math.floor(interval / 60000)
        interval -= 60000 * Math.floor(interval / 60000);
        const seconds = Math.floor(interval / 1000);
        document.getElementByid("sentence").innerHTML= ("Happy hour finished in " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the time() function with your `innerHTML` try?

Comment: Typo. "Id" instead of "ID", javascript is case sensitive

Comment: @RichardYan is right use `getElementById` instead of `getElementByID`.

Comment: @RichardYan - Absolutely -> 
I can see a document.getElementByid . It is wrong. Use document.getElementById as given below :

document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML=("Happy hour starts in " + 12 + ":" + 30 + ":" + 50);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error are bunch of typos as mentioned in the comments.
All you had to do was: use `getElementById` instead of `getElementByID` or `getElementByid`. (notice how 'Id' is spelt)

Here is a sample working code:

```js
function time() {
    let date = new Date();
    date.setHours(16);
    date.setMinutes(0);
    let day = date.getDate();
    date.setSeconds(0)
    date.setMilliseconds(0); // set happy hour for the day
    let interval = date - Date.now(); //calculate ms between current time and happy hour time

    //case when happy hour is later than current date, on the same day
  
    if (interval > 0) {
        const hour = Math.floor(interval / 3600000);
        interval -= 3600000 * Math.floor(interval / 3600000);
        const minutes = Math.floor(interval / 60000)
        interval -= 60000 * Math.floor(interval / 60000);
        const seconds = Math.floor(interval / 1000);
        document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = ("Happy hour starts in " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
    } else if (interval < 0 && interval < -3600000) { //happy hour gone, time left until it starts tomorrow
        date.setDate(++day);
        console.log(date);
        interval = date - Date.now();
        const hour = Math.floor(interval / 3600000);
        interval -= 3600000 * Math.floor(interval / 3600000);
        const minutes = Math.floor(interval / 60000);
        interval -= 60000 * Math.floor(interval / 60000);
        const seconds = Math.floor(interval / 1000)
        document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = ("Happy hour starts in " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
    } else { //happy hour started, but didn't finish yet
        const hour = Math.floor(interval / 3600000);
        interval -= 3600000 * Math.floor(interval / 3600000);
        const minutes = Math.floor(interval / 60000)
        interval -= 60000 * Math.floor(interval / 60000);
        const seconds = Math.floor(interval / 1000);
        document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = ("Happy hour finished in " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
    }
}
time()
```

```html
<p id="sentence"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `javascript.js` is a file you need to load, containing the definition of the `time` function, then this will not work:

```
<script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript">
    time();
</script>
```

A `script` tag with a `src` attribute will simply load the script from the given URL, and ignore any contents.

It looks like you want to load the file and then call the function: in that case you can do it like this:

```
<script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>time();</script>
```

Comment: said a `console.log` statement worked though. So I assume the script is being loaded up alright.

Comment: Yes, the script would have been loaded fine. But the `time()` call that you had inside the script tags would have been ignored.

Comment: what I meant is that I checked the variables if they are okay

Answer (score 0):

You should use DOM node it's pretty easy especially for your certain use,
Html will be as following

```
<div id="div1">
</div>
<script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript">
        time();
    </script>
```

Javascript:

```
var para = document.createElement("p");
var text = document.createTextNode("Happy hour starts in " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
para.appendChild(text);

var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);
```

Check https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp to understand it even better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead or pass your function that get detail or hours minutes and seconds

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Time</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id = "sentence"> </p>

    
    <script>
        const hour = new Date().getHours();
        const minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
        const seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
        document.getElementById('sentence').innerHTML = "Happy hour starts in " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Run the snippet for the output

Comment: there are 3 cases: happy hour started and it's not finished yet so display time left until it's finished, didn\t start yet so display time until it starts, and finished for today so display time until tomorrow's happy hour start

Comment: can I see what happens in your time function?